# How can I run Python scripts in terminal with Canopy installation?

Tags: python, terminal, canopy

I'd like to run Python scripts in the terminal using

```
$ chmod +x filename.py
$ \.filename.py
```

However, when I do this, I get errors telling me that some libraries do not exist, pandas for example.

I use Enthought Canopy to prototype a lot of my scripts, and I tried to make it my default installation by going to Preferences>"Set as Default", but have had no success.

I suspect it is one of two things:

1) My 'shebang' line `#!/usr/bin/python` points to the wrong installation.

2) The version of python I am running does not have the libraries I installed on Canopy. When I enter `python` into terminal, the following is returned:

```
Enthought Canopy Python 2.7.9 | 64-bit | (default, Jun 30 2015, 19:41:21) 
[GCC 4.2.1 (Based on Apple Inc. build 5658) (LLVM build 2335.6)] on darwin
```

How can I run my scripts that I write and test in Canopy in the terminal?

Comment: Change your shebang line to point to Canopy's python? Actually, I prefer to use this for shebang ``#!/usr/bin/env python``

Comment: It's because of this kind of thing that I switched to [Anaconda](https://www.continuum.io/downloads). It seems to play better with the system Python.

Answer (score 0):

When you are in the Canopy GUI Python prompt, what is the output of `sys.prefix`? That prefix (plus `bin/`) should be at the head of your PATH. And that prefix (plus `bin/python`) should be in your shebang.